# Javascript for loop hanging

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to use the Google Charts API to create a chart that has values dynamically given to it. The following code is supposed to take an array of values and populate the chart with them, but is instead hanging and killing the page. I am assuming that the for loop is not ending - but I can't figure out what is wrong.

Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  function drawChart(values) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
    data.addRows(values.length);

    for(i=0; i <= values.length; i+3) {
        data.setValue(values[i], values[i+1], values[i+2]);
    }

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240, legend: 'none', gridlineColor: '#fff', chartArea:{left:0,top:20}});
  }

  function stockFractal(){

  }

</script>
```

Comment: You never increment the `i` variable in the third expression of the `for` clause.

Comment: It looks like you are not incrementing your index. try chaging the i+3 to i+=3 in the last element of the for loop.

Comment: Guys, those are answers not comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not incrementing the `i` variable in the for loop; you want `i+=3` not `i+3`.

```
for (i=0; i <= values.length; i+=3)
```

Comment: Also, I think you want to change to condition from `<=` to `<`.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem(s)

You're right that the loop never terminates.

That's because this:

```
for(i=0; i <= values.length; i+3) {
```

does not increment `i`. It just creates a value which is the result of adding `3` to `i`... then discards that value.

It also seems likely that you meant `<`, not `<=`, since array indexes go from `0` to `values.length - 1`.

I also recommend the use of `var`.

---

### Solution

Write:

```
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i = i + 3) {
```

or just:

```
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i += 3) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0; i <= values.length; i+3) {
```

Should really read:

```
for(i=0; i <= values.length; i=i+3) {
```